# Select one row only if a value exists in another

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a query for wherein data comes from client and main approval records into a mapping table. which first checks for client approval if data is available for client approval, then it should fetch client approval. If no data is available for client then it should fetch main approval records for a particular date. The following query:

```
SELECT * FROM employee_map
  WHERE DATE = '2013-11-13 00:00:00'
    AND (WORKDAIRY_APPROVAL='ClientApproval' XOR WORKDAIRY_APPROVAL='MainApproval')
```

is giving 2 rows output for 13th date , but if I change the date to 20th I am getting main approval. If both main and client approval are available I need only client approval data.

```
 ------------------------------- --------------------------------------- 
 MAP_ID CATEGORY EMP_ID   DATE       EMP_NAME EMP_SAL APPROVAL
 ------------------------------------------ 
   1    DIRECT    1     11/13/2013    JOHN    5,000  MainApproval
   2    DIRECT    1     11/13/2013    JOHN    5,000  ClientApproval
   3    DIRECT    2     11/20/2013    RAJ     2,000  MainApproval
   4    DIRECT    3     11/21/2013    Ram     1,000  ClientApproval
```

please help me out .

Comment: This may be useful: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM employee_map em 
JOIN
(SELECT EMP_NAME, MAX(APPROVAL) AS APPROVAL FROM employee_map em 
  WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013-11-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-11-13 00:00:00'
    AND (WORKDAIRY_APPROVAL='ClientApproval' XOR WORKDAIRY_APPROVAL='MainApproval')) A
ON A.EMP_NAME=em.EMP_NAME and A.APPROVAL = em.APPROVAL
```

Something like this if Names are unique

Comment: HI MAHMOUD THANK YOU VERY MUCH FOR SPARING YOUR VALUABLE TIME FOR HELPING ME OUT.I GOT IT CORRECT FOR SINGLE DATE.CAN YOU ALSO HELP ME FOR MULTIPLE DATES .SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_MAP WHERE DATE = '2013-11-20 00:00:00' AND WORKDAIRY_APPROVAL =(
SELECT MIN(WORKDAIRY_APPROVAL) FROM EMPLOYEE_MAP WHERE DATE = '2013-11-20 00:00:00').it worked for single date.how to work for multiple .dates